# Re-importing C# .dll in PowerShell does not update classes

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dll, .net-assembly

I currently have a PowerShell script which uses Add-Type to import some classes from a C# .dll.

I added some methods to my class but am unable to use them because I get a method not found exception.

For example, I added a function like this to my class TestClass.cs:

```cs
public string giveMeAString(string myString)
{
    return myString;
}
```

At the top of my script I import the .dll like `Add-Type -Path $pathToDll`

As expected, before the Add-Type call I am not able to create an instance of this class. After the call is fine using `$testClass = [TestClass]::new()`

However, I cannot use the method `$testClass.giveMeAString()` because it doesn't exist. I get a method not found exception.

I have tried deleting the dll and running `dotnet build`, I've tried `dotnet clean`, I've tried using `Import-Module $pathToDll` instead, I've tried doing all that and then restarting my computer, and probably a couple more things. I'm at a total loss and my project is completely dead in the water until I get this working.

To complicate things further, if I create a console app in .NET and import the class there, I am able to access the method just fine.

For reference, this is on visual studio code using omnisharp.

Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: You can't unload the assembly from the application once loaded, so you'll have to start a new instance of `powershell.exe` and re-import the assembly again.

Comment: Interesting. I definitely did that. In fact I restarted my entire system and was still getting the error.

Comment: And you're sure `$pathToDll` is the path to the latest build? Could be different if you changed build profile or settings in VS in the meantime

Comment: Yeah I actually deleted the old .dll before building it again to make certain

Comment: That sure is odd. Have you tried creating a new script and paste in the contents of the original one? And you are sure you are not mixing up `Debug` vs `Release` builds of the dll? (that has tripped me up on numerous occasions). As an aside, instead of `Add-Type` in newer versions of PS (5 and up? -  not sure) you can use `using module`.

Comment: I'm not certain about the builds. I'm brand new to C#. I did delete the .dlls from both the debug folder and the obj folder. I couldn't find it hiding anywhere else. I will try the using module that's really interesting. I only need to support 5.1+ so that would work.

Comment: Right. I know a bit of C#, not great with PS. But I have done what you are trying extensively (i.e. bringing in my C# modules into PS). Never ran into trouble, but one of the things that tripped me up the first few times is that PS is very aggressive when it comes to 'caching' (for lack of a better word) stuff. If you change the C# dll, make sure you restart PS.A hacky way of testing if your reference in PS actually points to the dll would be to run the PS, then build the dll. The build should error saying the dll is in use.

Comment: My understanding so far is that the Add-Type imports the classes and the ```using module``` lets you reference the classes without specifying the entire namespace. So a class with namespace 'Module.Classes.Generic.TestClass' would have to be referenced in PS as ```[Module.Classes.Generic.TestClass]``` without the using statement. Otherwise with ```using namespace Module.Classes.Generic``` at the top of the script you could reference like ```TestClass``` by itself. No expert though.

Comment: That's `using namespace`, not the same as `using module`.

Comment: My ignorance about PS shows: for a C# assembly you would use `using assembly`. `using module` is for PS modules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223428/discussion-between-arno-van-boven-and-efie).